# Generic is not treated as Union

Tags: typescript, generics, union-types, mapped-types

The following code snippet is not working as expected. Somehow the K generic is not treated as a union (I think). What am I missing here. Why is this happening?

```
type GraphSubAttributeNames<N extends ApiModelNames, K extends GraphSubAttributeKeys<N>> =
GraphSubAttributesMap<N> extends never ?
    'never' :
    GraphSubAttributesMap<N>[K] extends MapRelation ?
        GetGraphRelationMap<N, K> extends never ?
            'case 1' :
            'case 2' :
        'case 3'


type T1 = GraphSubAttributeNames<'artist', 'portrait'> // 'case 3', which is correct
type T2 = GraphSubAttributeNames<'artist', 'heroArtwork'> // 'case 2', which is also correct
type T3 = GraphSubAttributeNames<'artist', 'heroArtwork' | 'portrait'> // case 3, but should be 'case 3' | 'case 2'
```

Unfortunately I failed to reproduce this with a minimal example.

Missing types (also I don't think they are part of the problem):

```
import {Artist, Footer, Site, Artwork, StrapiUser, Navigation, Exhibition, StrapiMedia} from "~/models"

type UnpackArray<T> = T extends (infer A)[] ? A : T

type StrapiAttributes = 'createdAt' | 'updatedAt' | 'publishedAt' | 'createdBy' | 'updatedBy'
type StripeStrapiAttributes<T extends StrapiApiTypes> = Omit<T, StrapiAttributes>

type MapRelation = {
    key: keyof ApiModelMap,
    many: boolean
}
// types of relations can be either a type or MapRelation
type ApiModelMap = {
    artist: {
        type: Artist
        relations: {
            portrait: StrapiMedia
            heroArtwork: {key: 'artworks', many: false}
        }
    }
    artworks: {
        type: Artwork[],
        relations: {
            figure: StrapiMedia
        }
    }
    exhibitions: {
        type: Exhibition[]
    }
    sites: {
        type: Site[]
    }
    navigation: {
        type: Navigation
    }
    footer: {
        type: Footer
    }
}
type StrapiApiTypes = {
    [P in keyof ApiModelMap]: ApiModelMap[P]['type']
}
type ApiRelation = {key: ApiModelNames}

type ApiModelNames = keyof ApiModelMap
type ApiModel<T extends ApiModelNames> = UnpackArray<ApiModelMap[T]['type']>
type ApiModelIsArray<T extends ApiModelNames> = ApiModelMap[T]['type'] extends [] ? true : never
type GraphSubAttributesMap<N extends ApiModelNames> = ApiModelMap[N] extends { relations: unknown } ? ApiModelMap[N]['relations'] : never
type GraphSubAttributeKeys<N extends ApiModelNames> = keyof GraphSubAttributesMap<N>

type GetGraphRelationMap<N extends ApiModelNames, K extends GraphSubAttributeKeys<N>> = GraphSubAttributesMap<N>[K] extends ApiRelation ?
  GraphSubAttributesMap<GraphSubAttributesMap<N>[K]['key']> :
  never
type GetGraphRelationType<N extends ApiModelNames, K extends GraphSubAttributeKeys<N>> = GraphSubAttributesMap<N>[K] extends ApiRelation ?
  UnpackArray<ApiModelMap[GraphSubAttributesMap<N>[K]['key']]['type']> :
  never
```

Comment: Hello, your snippet has several types missing. Can you include them please?

Comment: I added them but I don't think are relevant to the problem I have.

Comment: ① Please provide a [mre] that others can copy and paste into their own IDEs to see your issue and only your issue.  That means all third-party or private types and values need to be defined, or even better, replaced with built-in things.  And anything *not* needed should be removed. Even if we can solve your issue as-is it would be helpful if you could make the code a nice clean standalone example.

Comment: ② Presumably the issue is that your type needs to be distributive over unions in `K`, which can be accomplished by wrapping in a distributive conditional type as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WPgaLm). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining (but please do the [mre] thing first); if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting the expected result is that when your union isn't distributed while checking. To make it work, we have to make you type to check each item of the union separately, which can be done in numerous ways, but the basic one is to check `K extends K` at the beginning of `GraphSubAttributeNames`.  You can interpret `K extends K` as a for loop through in union where `K` first will be `"heroArtwork"` and `"portrait"` afterwards.

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nllk5N)

Comment: Thank you! This could be exactly my problem. I'll check later and approve this answer, if it is solving my problem.